# Uniformly powerful test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

> Suppose we are given a random sample $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ from a distribution
>   with density:
>
> $$f(x;θ) = θx^{θ−1}, 0 < x < 1$$
>
> Find the UMP critical region of significance level $α$ for testing
>   H0: $θ = θ_0$ against H1: $θ < θ_0$.

\begin{align}
C&=\{x:L(θ_o)/L(θ_1)<Κ\}  \\
 &=\{x: θ_o x^{(θ_o-1)}/θ_1 x^{(θ_1-1)}<K\}   \\
 &=\{x: (θ_ο/θ_1) x^{(θ_o-1-θ_1+1)}<K\}  \\
 &=\{x: (θ_ο/θ_1) x^{(θ_ο-θ_1)}<K\}  \\
 &=\{x: x^{(θ_ο-θ_1)}<Κ_1\}  \\
 &=\{x: x<K_2\}
\end{align}
Would this be correct up to now?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I have done my best to edit your post using the $\LaTeX$ formatting features that our site affords. Please ensure that it still says what you want it to.